# c++ and openCV with windows8: VideoWriter class not opening

Tags: c++, opencv, video, windows-8

I am trying to record a video using openCV's class VideoWriter.

Using the following function,

```
void addFrameToVideo(Mat& frame)
{
    if(_vid.open("test.avi", CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 30, frame.size(), 1))
        cout << "here" << endl;

    _vid.write(frame);
}
```

_vid is a variable of type VideoWriter and I can imshow frame with no problems.

The if condition never verifies, since the program never outputs "here".
However, this code actually creates a "test.avi" file in the directory, but it remains empty.
I've tried several different compression methods with no success.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the codec could not be found in your system. You should try using different codecs. Alternatively, you can pass the value -1 instead of `CV_FOURCC()` and a window will pop up at runtime that contains all the codec installed on your system and ask you to select the one to use (this only works on Windows).